# Inserting Data from one form into two tables

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need to insert data from one form in two tables in CakePHP 3.0.

I know I can't use `saveAll()` since that is deprecated. 
The two tables are `Users` and `Addresses`

Foreign key `id(Users)` and `user_id(Addresses)`

In `UsersTable` initialize has `$this->hasOne('Addresses');` and in `AddressesTable` `$this->belongsTo('Users');`

This is my add.ctp:

```
<legend><?= __('Add User') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
        echo $this->Form->input('role', [
        'options' => ['admin' => 'Admin', 'chinateam' => 'China Team', 'italianteam' => 'Italian team', 'reseller'=>'Reseller']
    ]);
        echo $this->Form->input('Address.address');
    ?>
```

UserController.php

```
public function add() {
$this->log('Quote Controller --> Add Method...1');
$this->log($this->request->data);
$user = $this->Users->newEntity();
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
  $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data, ['associated' => ['Addresses']]); 
  if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
    $this->Flash->success('The user has been saved.');
    //return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
  } else {
    $this->Flash->error('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.');
  }
}
$this->set(compact('user'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
```

This script inserts data in `Users` table but not in `Addresses` table.

Comment: You can 1st insert data in Master table and then in child table

Comment: In my case...  I created foreign key in this way

ALTER TABLE users
ADD FOREIGN KEY (id)
REFERENCES addresses(user_id);

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but you should get the point. And in case you're experiencing foreign key problems (what you are showing here would prevent inserting users when no address with a `user_id` exists that matches the users `id`, I suspect this should work the other way around), then that's probably something for a new question.